# Moving Laravel 5.4 project on CentOS 6 (Linux) - permission denied issue

Tags: linux, laravel-5.4, centos6

I have moved laravel projects before on shared hosting but not to university CentOS server.

I have put laravel public folder files inside public_html and I have put all other laravel project files under blog folder.

```
Root
 -blog
  -entire project files
 -public_html
  -all the public files
```

I changed 2 lines in index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../blog/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../blog/bootstrap/app.php';
```

As you can see I have added /blog

I have access to SSH shell, and below are the list of errors:

```
PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 10:43:58 2017] [error] [client 137.195.14.30] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 10:43:58 2017] [error] [client 137.195.14.30] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#5 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/lara in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729
[Thu Jun 08 11:54:48 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 11:54:48 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 11:54:48 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#5 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/lara in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729
[Thu Jun 08 11:58:06 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  require(/home/cs/username/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cs/username/public_html/index.php on line 22
[Thu Jun 08 11:58:06 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/cs/username/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/public_html/index.php on line 22
[Thu Jun 08 11:58:09 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  require(/home/cs/username/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cs/username/public_html/index.php on line 22
[Thu Jun 08 11:58:09 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/cs/username/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/public_html/index.php on line 22
[Thu Jun 08 11:58:12 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  require(/home/cs/username/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cs/username/public_html/index.php on line 22
[Thu Jun 08 11:58:12 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/cs/username/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/public_html/index.php on line 22
[Thu Jun 08 11:58:14 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  require(/home/cs/username/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cs/username/public_html/index.php on line 22
[Thu Jun 08 11:58:14 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/cs/username/public_html/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/public_html/index.php on line 22
[Thu Jun 08 12:05:35 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 12:05:35 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 12:05:35 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel',  in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729
[Thu Jun 08 12:05:38 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 12:05:38 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 12:05:38 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel',  in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729
[Thu Jun 08 12:05:46 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444, referer: http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~mf156/
[Thu Jun 08 12:05:46 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444, referer: http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~mf156/
[Thu Jun 08 12:05:46 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel',  in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729, referer: http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~mf156/
[Thu Jun 08 12:07:33 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 12:07:33 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 12:07:33 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel',  in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729
[Thu Jun 08 12:55:51 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 12:55:51 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 12:55:51 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel',  in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729
[Thu Jun 08 12:56:05 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444, referer: http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~mf156/
[Thu Jun 08 12:56:05 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444, referer: http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~mf156/
[Thu Jun 08 12:56:05 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel',  in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729, referer: http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~mf156/
[Thu Jun 08 12:56:11 2017] [crit] [client 92.98.49.227] (13)Permission denied: /home/cs/username/public_html/app/Http/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer: http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~mf156/
[Thu Jun 08 13:13:58 2017] [alert] [client 92.98.49.227] /home/cs/username/public_html/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Thu Jun 08 13:14:09 2017] [alert] [client 92.98.49.227] /home/cs/username/public_html/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Thu Jun 08 13:14:14 2017] [alert] [client 92.98.49.227] /home/cs/username/public_html/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Thu Jun 08 13:21:42 2017] [alert] [client 92.98.49.227] /home/cs/username/public_html/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Thu Jun 08 13:21:52 2017] [alert] [client 92.98.49.227] /home/cs/username/public_html/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Thu Jun 08 13:21:54 2017] [alert] [client 92.98.49.227] /home/cs/username/public_html/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Thu Jun 08 13:21:55 2017] [alert] [client 92.98.49.227] /home/cs/username/public_html/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Thu Jun 08 13:21:58 2017] [alert] [client 92.98.49.227] /home/cs/username/public_html/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Thu Jun 08 13:22:01 2017] [alert] [client 92.98.49.227] /home/cs/username/public_html/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Thu Jun 08 13:22:20 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 13:22:20 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 13:22:20 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel',  in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729
[Thu Jun 08 13:29:56 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel',  in /home/cs/username/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729, referer: http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~mf156/
[Thu Jun 08 13:35:34 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 13:35:34 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 13:35:34 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#5 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/lara in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729
[Thu Jun 08 13:35:40 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] File does not exist: /home/cs/username/public_html/public
[Thu Jun 08 13:35:45 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 13:35:45 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 13:35:45 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#5 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/lara in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729
[Thu Jun 08 13:36:48 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(/home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 13:36:48 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Kernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[Thu Jun 08 13:36:48 2017] [error] [client 92.98.49.227] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class App\\Http\\Kernel does not exist' in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#1 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(608): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel')\n#2 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(564): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#3 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(709): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#4 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(248): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->makeWith('App\\\\Http\\\\Kernel', Array)\n#5 /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/lara in /home/cs/username/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 729
```

Answer (score 0):

If public_html/ is your web root directory, then you might want to place ALL your Laravel files inside of the web root directory. Laravel should know how to use its own public folder. You shouldn't have to change the autoload paths.

For permissions to other important Laravel directories, please read this:

"Directory Permissions

After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the  storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set."

Comment: if I place everything in public_html then all the files are accessible from url. its bad from security end.

Comment: If that is the case, then your web server might need to be reconfigured. You should not be seen a "directory listing" of your files. You should be seen the Laravel welcome page.

Comment: yes I see list of files and not the welcome page. How to reconfigure it?

Comment: Since that is a University server and you are in a shared account, you may need to contact the System's Administrator. The changes will most likely need to be made on the webserver side. So you would need root access.

Comment: yes you are right. But the thing is I can run laravel project using php artisan serve. I can view it in localhost:8000 and it would run in my shared system. If I put files of basic laravel project (laravel new blog) it would run on main server. the one that I have built throws those errors

Comment: The errors you were seeing are likely from not having all your files inside of the web root directory. So that was the first issue. Even though you can run "php artisan serve", you would still need port 8000 open through your University's firewall (which most likely won't be for security reasons).

Comment: I hope my answers have helped you somehow. If you will, please mark this as your best answer.